# Check if Xml Node has an Attribute

Tags: c#, xml

How do I check if a node has particular attribute or not.

What I did is:

```
string referenceFileName = xmlFileName;
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(referenceFileName);

while (textReader.Read())
{
  XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;

  // if node type is an element
  if (nType == XmlNodeType.Element)
  {
    if (textReader.Name.Equals("Control"))
    {
      if (textReader.AttributeCount >= 1)
      {
        String val = string.Empty;
        val = textReader.GetAttribute("Visible");
        if (!(val == null || val.Equals(string.Empty)))
        {

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any function to check that a given attribute is present or not?

Comment: The word is "check", not "chk".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, I don't think there is any method in XmlTextReader class which can tell you whether a particular attribute exists or not.

You can do one thing to check

```
if(null == textReader.GetAttribute("Visible"))
{
   //this means attribute doesn't exist
}
```

because [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c932kx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says about `GetAttribute` method

```
    Return the value of the specified attribute. If the attribute is not found,
 a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned.
```

Comment: Will you suggeset any other class which has method to check whether a particular attribute exists or not.

Comment: Not in my knowledge. I don't know any method which returns bool value about whether the attribute exists or not. All I know returns null if attribute doesn't exist

Comment: As [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=netframework-4.5) says: "Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the XmlReader class instead."

Answer (score 9):

Found this: http://csharpmentor.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/safely-retrive-attribute-from-xml-node.html

You can convert the XmlNode to an XmlElement then use the HasAttribute method to check.  I just tried it and it works - very useful.

Sorry its not an example using your code - I'm in a hurry but hope it helps future askers!

Comment: This answer is grossly underrated. This link is also well worth checking out. +1

Comment: +1 from me, too.  It gave me the idea of the following construct to use in a method-call that needs the string or empty if the attribute exists:
`(node as XmlElement).HasAttribute("name2") ? node.Attributes["name2"].Value : String.Empty`

Answer (score 2):

Try out LINQ-To-XML (query below might require minor fixes since I'm not have XML you are using)

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Testxml.xml");  

// It might be that Control element is a bit deeper in XML document
// hierarchy so if you was not able get it work please provide XML you are using
string value = xdoc.Descendants("Control")
                  .Where(d => d.HasAttributes
                              && d.Attribute("Visible") != null
                              && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Attribute("Visible").Value))
                  .Select(d => d.Attribute("Visible").Value)
                  .Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

//Check xml element value if exists using XmlReader

```
      using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("XMLSTRING")))
       {

           if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("XMLNODE")) 

            {
                string nodeValue = xmlReader.ReadElementString("XMLNODE");                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking refernce from Harish's answer,following code worked for me

```
 XmlTextReader obj =new XmlTextReader("your path");
    //include @before"" if its local path
      while (obj.Read()) { 
      Console.WriteLine(obj.GetAttribute("name"));
      obj.MoveToNextAttribute();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is not using a reader and just an XmlDocument try XmlAttributeCollection/XmlAttribute

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try{
doc.Load(_indexFile);
    foreach(XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){
        XmlAttributeCollection attrs = node.Attributes;
        foreach(XmlAttribute attr in attrs){
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText + ": " + attr.Name + " - " + attr.Value);
            if(attr.Name == "my-amazing-attribute")
            {
                //Do something with attribute
            }
        }
    }
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Do something with ex
}
```